# how to get username outside the session in Android

Tags: android, facebook, string

I am working with Android facebook integration. I am trying to insert username into local database.I can't get username outside the if loop...how to get string value s outside the function.....

here is my code...

```
    Session.openActiveSession(getActivity(), true, new Session.StatusCallback()
           {

                    @Override
                public void call(Session session, SessionState state,
                Exception exception) {

                        if (session.isOpened()){
                                Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session,new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                @Override
                       public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {

                           if (user != null){
                                 t=(TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                                 p = (ProfilePictureView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.profilePictureView1);
                                   p.setProfileId(user.getId());
                                 s=user.getName();
                             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                 t.setText(s);
                                 s1=user.getId();


                            }
                        }

                    });
                } 
            }

              });

          if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
               String contact_id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( _ID ));
               String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( DISPLAY_NAME ));
                     int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( HAS_PHONE_NUMBER )));

                   output.append("\n First Name:" + name);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(PhoneCONTENT_URI, null, Phone_CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[] { contact_id }, null);
                      while (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(NUMBER));
                         output.append("\n Phone number:" + phoneNumber);
                                                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),""+name+""+phoneNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    //String s1=t.getText().toString();
                     //s=user.getName();
                    //String s1=user.getId();
                     //HashMap<String, String>queryValues =  new  HashMap<String, String>();
                     //queryValues.put("user",s.toString());
                     //String s3=phoneNumber.toString();
                    //String s8;
                    //s8=t.getText().toString();
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"in contacts"+s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     //queryValues.put("uid",s1.toString());
                    // queryValues.put("contact",s3.toString());

                     //db.insertuser(queryValues);
                          }
                     }
                   }
```

Comment: assign `user.getUsername` to a String var should do it

Comment: i am getting the username...i just want it to retrieve it outside the if loop of the session and toast it into the last toast statement

Comment: Declare `String s` as a global private variable. Then you can access `s` wherever you want inside the class.

Comment: i already did as u said..but i can't access it in the last toast

Comment: Check your `cursor.getCount()`. Make sure it is > 0 to make the if statement valid.